# How to send HashMap data from one activity to another?

Tags: android, android-intent, hashmap, android-bundle

I am setting resultActivty. I have to get back the result so, something I am doing like

I have tried but here I am getting only the keys not value

```
  Intent i = new Intent(this, CustImageSignatureUploadFragment.class);
        i.putExtra("uniqueBiometric", uniqueBiometricList);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        finish();

    else if (requestCode == File_Key.BIOMETRICUNIQUE) {
                    uniqueBiometricList = (HashMap<String, 
   CommKycUpload>)data.getSerializableExtra("uniqueBiometric");


   CommKycUpload is my pojo which is implementing  parcelable
```

Comment: I am not getting value , getting only key while using   (HashMap<String, 
   CommKycUpload>)data.getSerializableExtra("uniqueBiometric");  but My CommKycUplaod is Pojo and implementing Parceleable

Comment: Looks like you've solved your problem. Please create an answer and accept that answer. This will help others and will remove the question from the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for populating of the intent:

```
val map = HashMap<String,YourObject>()

    val intent = Intent()
    intent.putExtra("SIZE", map.size)

    for (k in 0..map.size) {
        intent.putExtra("KEY"+k, map.keys.toList()[k])
        intent.putExtra("VALUE"+k, map[map.keys.toList()[k]])
    }
```

And this for reading it back:

```
val mapReceived = hashMapOf<String,YourObject>()

    val intReceived = getIntent()
    if (intReceived.hasExtra("SIZE")) {
        val size = intReceived.getIntExtra("SIZE", 0)

        for (k in 0..size) {
            mapReceived[intReceived.getStringExtra("KEY"+k)] = intReceived.getParcelableExtra("VALUE"+k)
        }
    }
```

May be not the smartest one, but probably should work

In Java:

Writing:

```
HashMap<String, ActivityBase> map = new HashMap<String,ActivityBase>();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("SIZE", map.size());

    for (int k=0; k<=map.size(); k++){
        intent.putExtra("KEY"+k, (String)map.keySet().toArray()[k]);
        intent.putExtra("VALUE"+k, (ActivityBase) map.get(map.values().toArray()[k]));
    }
```

Reading:

```
HashMap<String, ActivityBase> mapReceived = new HashMap<String,ActivityBase>();

    Intent intReceived = getIntent();
    if (intReceived.hasExtra("SIZE")) {
        int size = intReceived.getIntExtra("SIZE", 0);

        for (int k=0; k<=map.size(); k++){
            mapReceived.put(intReceived.getStringExtra("KEY"+k), intReceived.getParcelableExtra("VALUE"+k));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are You writing in kotlin, if yes please try to write in Java

Answer (score 0):

```
For example, when sending the intent:

HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
hashMap.put("key", "value");
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("map", hashMap);
startActivity(intent);
And then in the receiving Activity:

protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Intent intent = getIntent();
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>)intent.getSerializableExtra("map");
Log.v("HashMapTest", hashMap.get("key"));
}
```

Comment: I am doing same but my hashmap is HashMap<String, CommKycUpload> and CommKycUpload is pjo which is implementing Parcelable

Comment: So there I am getting only key not value

Comment: kindly check hashmap that contains values  while passing to another activity

Comment: Yes, I am getting value

Comment: But while getting into next activity it is not showing

Comment: This is the code from I am sending        =>   Intent i = new Intent(this, CustImageSignatureUploadFragment.class);
            i.putExtra("uniqueBiometric", uniqueBiometricList);

            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

Comment: setResult(RESULT_OK, i); why you are using setresult

Comment: And this is where I am getting =>   else if (requestCode == File_Key.BIOMETRICUNIQUE) {
                        uniqueBiometricList = (HashMap<String, CommKycUpload>)data.getSerializableExtra("uniqueBiometric");
                      }

Comment: I am using startActivityForResult for coming back to activity with result

Comment: This is my startActivityForResult     =>Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), BiometricActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("custMobile", mListener.getCustData().getPhoneNo());
                startActivityForResult(i, File_Key.BIOMETRICUNIQUE);

Answer (score 0):

`Hashmap` extends `Serializable` so  if your POJO also extends `Serializable` you can simply pass your `Hashmap<String,Object>` to another activity via intent

```
Hashmap<String,Object> data = new Hashmap<String,Object>();
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, Activity2.class);
intent.putSerializableExtra("data", data)
```

Comment: My pojo is extending Parcelable , In that case What can I do?

Comment: Thanks to all, but I got my solution myself, actually I was not not implementing parcelable in  my CommKycUpload Pojo  , Now I solved this. Thanks